# Implementing MVVM in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been playing around with Xamarin.Forms and I made a simple "Hello World" type of projects. I've been trying to convert the same project into an MVVM type of project just to get a feel of things. However, I'm having trouble on deciding what my Models should be. Here is how my project looks as of now:

Views/MainView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="TestGround.MainView">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label
                    Text="{Binding Greeting}"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                />
                <Entry
                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                />
                <Button
                    Text="Enter"
                    Command="{Binding SayHelloCommand}"
                />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Views/MainView.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestGround
{
    public partial class MainView : ContentPage
    {
        public MainView ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            this.BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace TestGround
{
    public class MainViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _greeting; //backing field for Greeting

        public string Greeting //implementation for Greeting method
        { 
            get { return _greeting; } 

            set 
            { 
                _greeting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged ("Greeting"); //Notify view that change has taken place

            }
        }

        public string Name { get; set; } //Name method for Entry field, completely useless

        public ICommand SayHelloCommand { get; set; } //ICommand binds to buttons in XAML

        public void SayHello() //Need a regular method to add to ICommand
        {
            Greeting = "Hello " + Name;
        }

        public MainViewModel ()
        {
            Greeting = "Its alive!";
            Name = "Enter name";

            SayHelloCommand = new Command(SayHello); //Regular command added to ICommand
        }



        #region PropertyChangedRegion

        public void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

    }
}
```

I have an empty Models folder and I don't understand the MVVM structure enough to decide what my Models should be. I was thinking that I should declare my methods in a Model and implement them in a ViewModel, but I am not sure.

Can someone please tell me which parts of my code would be a Model?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted the model would be the strings your're setting `Greeting` and `Name` with.  If your example became more advanced you might end up with a `Person` model object with a `Name` property that comes from some external source like a database or web service,

The view model would be responsible for retrieving the `Person` model object, possibly `GetPerson`(), and setting the `Name = Person.Name`.

The forms mobile CRM example [models](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/MobileCRM/MobileCRM.Shared/Models) and [view models](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/MobileCRM/MobileCRM.Shared/ViewModels).

> "So anything that interacts with a View in any way will go into the
>   ViewModel? So I could put the Greeting and Name properties in my
>   Model, and have them initialized in the ViewModel to display in the
>   View?"

Generally, there might be cases when you have view only concerns that don't need to interact with the view model.  Think of the view model has a headless representation of the view.  If you have a view model for login, it might have `Username`, `Password` properties, and a `Login` method for logging in.  When the user clicks the `Login` button the view model validates the `Username` and `Password` and then authenticates the user against some service.  At that point a view can be bound to allow a user to login.  A test could also be written to test the login process using the same view model.

Comment: So would I just declare the backing fields like _greeting in the Model? And then implement the Greeting method in my ViewModel?

Comment: Also, so basically my Models will contain Classes and my ViewModel will contain Objects of aforementioned Classes?

Comment: Generally yes, models are the representation of some state or data to display or process by the view model.  The view models is the thing that sits between the view and the model.  It's the traffic cop between the view and the data.

Comment: The view model has the Greeting property but a model could also have a Greeting property if that makes sense.

Comment: So anything that interacts with a View in any way will go into the ViewModel? So I could put the Greeting and Name properties in my Model, and have them initialized in the ViewModel to display in the View?